# Is there a way to make python return an error for wrong input text?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm creating a program that will have a yes or no option inside of it. I wondering if there is a way that I could make python return an "unauthorized text" if anything other than yes or no is entered.

Comment: There sure is! What have you already tried?

Comment: Also, it would be useful to have some indication of what your existing code looks like.

Comment: if text not in ['yes','no']: ## "unauthorized text" .

Comment: The answer to your question is: `yes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yes*, you could `raise` an `Exception` passing to it as parameter the necessary information.

```
def f(my_input):
    if my_input in ("Yes", "No"):
        return "Success"
    else:
        raise Exception("Unauthorized text")

print f("Yes")
print f("No")
print f("StackOverflow")
```

**Output:**

```
Success
Success
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
Exception: Unauthorized text
```

**Edit:** As @tripleee commented, if this is not what you were expecting, you could simple return a string:

```
def f(my_input):
    if my_input in ("Yes", "No"):
        return "Success"
    else:
        return "Unauthorized text"
```

Comment: While the question asked about raising an error, I don't think this is what the OP had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
if input.lower() == 'yes':
    # do one thing
elif input.lower() == 'no':
    # do another thing
else:
    print "unauthorized text"
```

Comment: You'll need more than `if yes`; Python will think `yes` is a boolean variable. Try `if input == 'yes'`.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. The 'yes' and 'no' part were just meant to be pseudocode, but I can see how that's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep asking until they get it right:

```
def getYesNo(msg=None):
    if msg is None: msg = "Yes or No?"
    choice = ''
    choices = {'yes': True, 'y': True, 'no': False, 'n': False}
    while choice.lower() not in choices:
        choice = raw_input(msg + ' ')
    return choices[choice]
```

If you want to raise an exception instead:

```
def getYesNo(msg=None):
    if msg is None: msg = "Yes or No?"
    choice = ''
    choices = {'yes': True, 'y': True, 'no': False, 'n': False}
    choice = raw_input(msg + ' ')
    if choice not in choices:
        raise ValueError, "Unauthorized Text"
    return choices[choice]
```